# How to access Azure SQL database server management UI via URL

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I used to use Azure a while ago (about a year) and an easy way to access your database was to go to: yourservername.database.windows.net it would prompt a login and you can access your DB's that way. But now, and not sure if it's because of the new design, when I go to this link I get a 503 error. I'm just looking for some answers as to a) can I not access this because of my account or did they just remove this from accessibility? and b) is there another way (without coding query statements) to easily add tables/data?

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with writing code to do it? You're using the cloud, right? Script it!

Comment: Yeah, I would but I need to build an application in 4 hours for a job interview, I kind of want to devote 99% of that time to development and just have a db ready with some dummy data I scraped.

Comment: Writing the commands yourself can be just as fast as a GUI, if you know the commands. And I would expect they want to know that you know the commands if it's a job interview.

Comment: I know SQL commands, I'm just not sure how to execute them into my db. If I had a query script open I can do it. I just don't know _how_ to get to the script, if that makes sense?

Comment: Well, you can connect to a SQL Server database using Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio. Will you have either of those available to you?

Comment: Oh yeah I have VS right now, I think I just need to do some research. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think this was the link for the old Silverlight SQL management page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old Silverlight based SQL Management UI available when hitting the database server URL from a web browser is only available for Azure SQL Database servers that are not V12 (the latest version).

In order for this UI to be made available for our database server, you must select NO for the "Create V12 server (Latest version)" option when provisioning a new Azure SQL database server.

As long as the Azure SQL database server is NOT V12, the Silverlight based Management UI will be available at the following URL:

```
https://{server_name}.database.windows.net
```